# Problems using Servo.h and VirtualWire.h in arduino

Tags: arduino, c

I'm using an Arduino Uno. My motive is to control a servo via wireless transmission using RF. So for that I have to use both Virtual Wire.h and Servo.h. But when I am compiling it shows me errors that is not defined and other problems. When I studied on net it shows that both uses Timer1 so we have to change the timer of Servo. So there are some suggestions and fixes found on net that guided me to use a new library called ServoTimer2.h.

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,21975.0.html

Now when i use this library it doesn't seem like its been included in the arduino library. Also the color of Servotimer2.h doesn't change also.

Errors showed while compiling

```c
#include <VirtualWire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

void setup(){}

void loop(){}
```

```
Servo\Servo.cpp.o: In function `__vector_11':
C:\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\Servo/Servo.cpp:103: multiple definition of `__vector_11'
VirtualWire\VirtualWire.cpp.o:C:\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.cpp:568: first defined here
```

Comment: What happens when you remove one of the two includes?

Comment: it works normally. Like the individuals are working perfectly but not together

Answer (score 3):

### On the compile problem

The problem is that both `Servo.cpp` and `VirtualWire.cpp` try to use the same interrupt vector.  In the `Servo.cpp` source (line 103 as mentioned in the error you saw):

```
#if defined(_useTimer1)
SIGNAL (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  handle_interrupts(_timer1, &TCNT1, &OCR1A);
}
#endif
```

In `VirtualWire.cpp` lin 568, as mentioned in the error you saw:

```
// Assume Arduino Uno (328p or similar)    
SIGNAL(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
#endif // __AVR_ATtiny85__    
{
    ... ISR code here ....
```

Arduino Uno has only a single 16-bit timer, and `Servo.cpp` library seems to want it.  The problem is that VirtualWire library also wants to use the only 16-bit timer available. You could try rewriting one of the two libraries to use 8-bit timers, but you may lose features and functionality.

### Using ServoTimer2

The ServoTimer2 library is meant to be a replacement for the servo library. This means you will need to download ServoTimer2 library, as it isn't a part of the standard Arduino distribution, put the `ServoTimer2.h` and `ServoTimer2.cpp` into `ServoTimer2` directory in your Arduino `libraries` directory (for me the Arduino directory is `/usr/share/arduino` so, I put the servotimer2 files into `/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ServoTimer2/`), and then replace

```
#include "Servo.h"
```

with

```
#include "ServoTimer2.h"
```

In your sketch. The commands you use with ServoTimer2 library are supposed to be identical or similar to the commands used with the Servo library with one difference:

> The usage and method naming is similar to the Arduino software [servo
>   library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/ComponentLib/Servo)  except that pulse widths are in microseconds not degrees.

So you should be able to keep most of your code. The only difference is that you'll declare your Servo object as `ServoTimer2` instead of `Servo` or `SoftwareServo`.

Comment: In ServoTimer2 how do i give write command. Can i use servo.write(degree between 0 to 180)

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry.